# POSTGRES, column "row_count" does not exist when using ROW_COUNT

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

After running my function I am trying to display the amount of updated rows to the panel like so:

```
  RAISE NOTICE 'updated rows= %', ROW_COUNT;
  commit;
  RAISE NOTICE 'updated rows= %', ROW_COUNT;
  commit;
  END;
```

however I get an error of:

```
ERROR:  column "row_count" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT ROW_COUNT
```

i'm pretty sure this is acceptable syntax, not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Where is the rest of your SQL?

Comment: i left it out for brevity but will edit back in for more detail

Comment: From here [Diagnostics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) you need to do: `GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT;` to use `ROW_COUNT`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not any automatics variable named `ROW_COUNT`. You should to use statement [`GET DIAGNOSTICS yourvar = ROW_COUNT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html).